# Thymeleaf - Best practice for checking for NULL when formatting (ie. dates)

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a Thymeleaf template code to **format a date**. There are times when that date will be `null` in the returned object.  What is the best way to check for `null` in Thymeleaf in this situation?  Currently the template is throwing the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot apply format on null
    at org.thymeleaf.util.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:37)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.DateUtils.format(DateUtils.java:182)
    at org.thymeleaf.expression.Dates.format(Dates.java:164)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can either use thymeleafs objects utility class [Objects](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.2/org/thymeleaf/expression/Objects.html) or validate the object before passing it to the template.

i prefer the prevalidation as you normally do not want to hack around in your template. also that way you keep your data loosely coupled from the view.

Comment: I went with this approach although I don't necessarily see handling a null value in the template a hack per se, but it does muck up the template and arguably breaks the separation of concerns for views and their data.

Answer (score 58):

You can also use a conditional expression on your object, so that the formatting method is only applied if you object is not null: `th:text="${myDate} ? ${#dates.format(myDate,...)}"`

Note there is no "else" part in the expression above, and in that case the expression will simply return null (making the `th:text` attribute write nothing).

*(Disclaimer required by StackOverflow: I am the author of thymeleaf)*

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I actually got this approach working but decided to validate the values on the server side to keep the templates more readable and "clean". Thanks for the response.

Comment: I think that this is actually a **bug** in Thymeleaf. The `dates.format` and `temporals.format` should simply return `null` in case that the input value is `null`. It is very annoying to add these boilerplate `if`s everywhere :(

Comment: I have similar issue, where as my data object is not null. it is giving me un -formatted date if I use this code "<td th:text="*{dateOfBirth}">06/23/2013</td>" but when I use 
<td th:text="${#temporals.format(*{dateOfBirth},'dd-mm-yyyy')}">06/23/2013</td> it gives me null... any idea @Daniel Femandez