# spring boot thymeleaf format date gives "Cannot retrieve hour from null"

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a spring boot application in which I am trying to display date of birth in a formatted manner. If i don't use the thymeleaf dates format option i was able to display the date but if use the format option it gives me the `"Cannot apply format on null"`.

```
 <td th:text="*{dateOfBirth}">06/23/2013</td>
 output: 1990-01-21 00:03:00.0

 <td th:text="${#dates.format(dateOfBirth,'dd-mm-yyyy')}">06/23/2013</td>
 output ::Cannot apply format on null
```

the dateOfBirth field in my pogo class is declared as below.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomeDateDeserializer.class)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd-mm-yyyy")
private Date dateOfBirth;
```

I have tried with difference combinations but all giving me the same error. Can any one help me what I am missing in here.

Comment: The answers of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825570 might be helpful

Comment: I have already gone thru that SO link. But in my case as I said the DateOfBirth field is having date and it is not null but still getting null when I try to print it by formating. If I don't format I am able to print the date

Comment: *Unrelated:** `mm` is wrong, it means minutes. You need to use `MM` to get month. --- Also, why do you specify format as `dd-MM-yyyy`, then give the sample text as `MM/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: sorry. I still get the same error even after changing it to MM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*{dateOfBirth}` has a specific meaning.  [When you use the `*` notation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#expressions-on-selections-asterisk-syntax), you are referring to a property of the `th:object` you have selected.  When you use a `${}` expression, you lose that.  In order to specify the same variable, you should use the `#object` expression variable (or name the complete path to the variable in question).

```
<td th:text="${#dates.format(#object.dateOfBirth,'dd-MM-yyyy')}">06/23/2013</td>
```

Note: Since you are already specifying the date format of your variable, I think that the [double-bracket syntax](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#conversion-services) should work for you:

```
<td th:text="${{#object.dateOfBirth}}">06/23/2013</td>
```

Comment: the 2nd one worked for me...thank you a lot...If I use the #dates.format I am still getting the error "Property or field 'dateOfBirth' cannot be found on null". What If I want to change the format in future with out changing the format in my java class. I just want to change the format in this thymeleaf page

Comment: @GhostRider did you use `#object.dateOfBirth` instead of `dateOfBirth` in the first example?  What are you using for `th:object`?