# #temporals.format() throws NullPointerException

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I'm struggling to format a LocalDate in Thymeleaf like so:

```html
    <div th:object="${objectWithDateField}">
        <span th:text="*{#temporals.format(date)}"></span>
    </div>
```

This throws a NPE with the message: `target is null for method format` where `target` refers to the parameter of the `format()` method.

So my question is: What am I doing wrong or is this a bug in Thymeleaf?

When I'm not formatting the date and just render it like the following it shows the date correctly.

```html
    <div th:object="${objectWithDateField}">
        <span th:text="*{date}"></span>
    </div>
```

I'm running this code in a unit test at the moment and added an assertion that confirms to me that the date is definitely not null before passing the object to the context (also confirmed by rendering without the call to `format()`).

I already tried the solutions from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825570/thymeleaf-best-practice-for-checking-for-null-when-formatting-ie-dates/13868142) and someone in the comments had the same problem I'm describing unfortunately without an answer.

I'm using the following versions:

- Spring Boot Starter Thymeleaf: 2.7.2
- ognl: 3.2.1 (I'm not using SpEL)

EDIT:

For clarification: I've registered my own `TemplateEngine` bean and annotated it with `@Primary` to be able to use Thymeleafs default dialect like so:

```java
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public TemplateEngine myTemplateEngine() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);

        TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        return templateEngine;
    }
```

The `thymeleaf-extras-java8time` is present in the runtime classpath as it's pulled in transitively via `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf`.

Comment: For clarification: Can you show how you have configured Thymeleaf? I don't know how you can use Spring Boot Starter Thymeleaf, but not be using SpEL - I am not familiar with that set-up. Also, just for clarification: You are using the `thymeleaf-extras-java8time` JAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution.

The `target` in the NPEs exception message was in fact not referring to the parameter of format (which is also named `target`). It is referring to the `#temporals` context object.

So to solve the problem I added the `Java8TimeDialect` from the above mentioned `thymeleaf-extras-java8time` library to my `TemplateEngine` bean like so:

```java
templateEngine.addDialect(new Java8TimeDialect());
```

From here on everything worked as expected.